# Delete text from a file using regular expressions

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I have lots of text in a file. I want to delete all text that are between symbols `===` and `<!!!>`. E.g.
`Text ===some comments<!!!> lala ===aaa<!!!>"` should be `Text lala` after running the command. I tried `sed -i -E "s/(===(.*)<!!!>)//" file`, but it doesn't work.

Edit:

````
Text ===

some commenkjghkb

ufjhbgdfxjhg


srtdfts

</!!!> 

lala ===aaa

</!!!>"```
````

should be `Text lala`

Comment: You have `<!!!>` in one and `</!!!` in the other. Make up your mind. Also do you mean that those spaces, newlines and `"\`\`\`` have to be removed?

Comment: @tmm try my second edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With perl regular expressions, you can do [non-greedy](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm) matches:

```
perl -pe 's/===.*?<!!!>//g' file
```

**Edit 1:** If you want to insert some text use that:

```
perl -pe 's/===.*?<!!!>/Text you want to insert/g' file
```

**Edit 2:** If it has to handle multiline comments as well use that:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s|===.*?</!!!>|insert|gs' file
```

We have to use the `s` modifier, which brings `.` to match also a newline. The `$/` variable of perl, which is the input separator, must be changed to undef. This is also called the "slurp" mode.

Comment: Nice! A second faster :)

Comment: what if i also need to add text? `===abc` instead of `===`, and `</!!!>`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: ok, anyway, I will remove my answer because 2 identical answers don't make any sense

Comment: @chaos `perl -pe 's/===abs.*?<\/!!!>//g' file` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @tmm Why sould it work? After `===` there is no string `abs`... What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @chaos sorry, i want to have a string `abs` after `===`, and delete comments only that start with `abs`

Comment: @tmm umm... Why place a string after `===` when you want to remove the whole part? Can you give *exact* input and output examples?

Comment: `Text ===abssome comments</!!!> lala ===aaa</!!!>"` should be `Text lala ===aaa</!!!>`

Comment: also, the file is big, so many comments can be in new lines

Comment: Can you add all that information in the question please? Also if comments in newlines should be removed too, it's a bit more tricky. Given an example of such a comment over multiple lines in your question.

Comment: amazing, thank you @chaos, wish i could upvote

Comment: You can also use `-0777` in place of `BEGIN{$/ = undef}`.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` which doesn't support non-greedy `*`, you'd need to use tricks like:

```
sed 's/_/_u/g;s/|/_p/g;s/<!!!>/|/g
     s/===[^|]*|//g
     s/|/<!!!>/g;s/_p/|/g;s/_u/_/g'
```

Or with some `sed` implementations:

```
sed 's/<!!!>/\
/g; s/===[^\n]*\n//g; s/\n/<!!!>/g'
```

To support multi-line matching (as per your edit), with recent versions of GNU sed, you can use the first one with `-z` option (assuming the file doesn't contain NUL characters) or use something like:

```
sed ':1
     $!{
       N
       b1
     }
     s/_/_u/g;s/|/_p/g;s/<!!!>/|/g
     s/===[^|]*|//g
     s/|/<!!!>/g;s/_p/|/g;s/_u/_/g'
```